# get the html code with jQuery of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with lots of stuffs. With a script I change the content et I have content1 for button1, content2 for button2. If a click on button1 the content2 disappear and the content1 appear.

I want to get the html code of the page displayed in the browser, not these of the content1.

Have you an idea ? Thanks :)

**EDIT:** I want the html code of the page **displayed** in the browser not in the page .html so .html() doesn't help me.

For Example: How can i do to get the content of the page : https://stackoverflow.com/ in a variable ? If possible with the balise html.

(ex: ... < h1 > Top Questions < /h1 > ... all in a variable ) I talk about the page displayed not the source code.

In my page I have differents div but I don't want to get all the html, I just want to get these displayed in the browser. If I have `<html> <body> <div id="content1"> blabla </div> <div id="content2"> blabla </div> </body> </html>` and with a script I display just content2. In the browser, just the content2 is displayed and I want to get `<html> <body> <div id="content2"> blabla </div> </body> </html>`

**EDIT:** my code :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
     <ul class="nav nav-list">
           <li>
               <a href="#section1">Section1</a>
               <ul class="nav nav-list">
                  <li ng-show="button1">
                     <a  href="#section1_1">Section1_1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li ng-show="!button1">
                     <a  href="#section1_2">Section1_2</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
 </div>
```

With a button I put `button1` to true and an other to false. So the page is different in function of this.
I want to get the html code when the button is to true or false. So whether :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
         <ul class="nav nav-list">
               <li>
                   <a href="#section1">Section1</a>
                   <li ng-show="button1">
                       <a  href="#section1_1">Section1_1</a>
                   </li>
               </li>
         </ul>
</div>
```

or :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
         <ul class="nav nav-list">
               <li>
                   <a href="#section1">Section1</a>
                   <li ng-show="!button1">
                       <a  href="#section1_2">Section1_2</a>
                   </li>
               </li>
         </ul>
</div>
```

In fact the result which is displayed.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. you are doing fine. every new question is like this.

Comment: It's not my issue, i want the html code of the page **displayed** in the browser, not in the page .html.

Comment: There is no HTML code displayed in the browser, normally. The HTML code is in the source code, it is not displayed by the browser. Take an example. We don't understand what you reaaly want to do.

Comment: I edited, do you undestand better ?

Comment: You want an html page that will display the source html of another html page? Or just a part of that page?

Comment: Just get the part of that page, only the part which is displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

```
    var $node = $('#myContainer'); // jQuery object of node to be cloned
    $node.find(':hidden').addClass('markedForRemoval');

    var $clone = $node.clone();

    $clone.find('.markedForRemoval').remove();

    // tidy up:
    $clone.find('.markedForRemoval').removeClass('markedForRemoval');
    $node.find('.markedForRemoval').removeClass('markedForRemoval');

    var codeHtml = $clone.html();
```

This is it :)

Answer (score 0):

`$('body').html();` will return you the content of body.

`$('body').html(var VARIABLE);` will change current content of body by VARIABLE

I guess you can do what you want with it!

EDIT :

To hide the div with ID=content1 :

```
$('#content1').hide();
```

To show it :

```
$('#content1').show();
```

To get code in a variable :

`var html = $('#content1').html();`

Comment: It's not my issue, i want the html code of the page **displayed** in the browser, not in the page .html.

Comment: @MartelBenjamin sorry ? explain yourself better please

Comment: Well not that much. The content of body will give you <h1>...</h1><p>...</p> etc ..., so what's wrong with getting it ?

Comment: In my page I have differents div but I don't want to get all the html, I just want to get these displayed in the browser. 
If I have `<html> <body> <div id="content1"> blabla </div> <div id="content2"> blabla </div> </body> </html>` and with a script I display just content2. In the browser, just the content2 is displayed and I want to get `<html> <body> <div id="content2"> blabla </div> </body> </html>`

Comment: Edited with what you want to maybe

Comment: Not exactly, in fact I want to get in a variable the html code like .html() but without the content hidden, just the part which is displayed.